# DataTable shows 1 insted of empty record message

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

This is my code for  the date table

```
var table = $('.MyNumbersTable').DataTable({
        "lengthMenu": [
            [10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
            [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]
        ],
        "aaSorting": [],
        "language": {
            "zeroRecords": "You don't have any numbers."
        }
});
```

The issue is when there are records in my numbers table it displays records, It is fine.
But when if there is no record in table it show '1' as record instead of display message.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see notes regarding `language.zeroRecords`:
https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.zeroRecords

> Note that language.emptyTable is shown when there is simply no
> information in the table at all (regardless of filtering), while this
> parameter is used for when the table is empty due to filtering.

It seems you may wish to use `language.emptyTable` : https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.emptyTable

Comment: Yes, You are right but I tried it with `language.emptyTable` but it is working same like `language.zeroRecords`. 
It displays message on empty searching result.

Comment: I solved the error. There are some conflict on data-table row counting. so it displays the number of row. And this answer is also useful to me.